# Run Query as Community User

Tags: community, rest-api, query, customer-community

We are using angular to display UI and Salesforce is being used to maintain database. We have a REST API class created which has the urlMapping. This class is used to find the records.

The API have few queries which have the where clause such that the data should display by filtering from logged in User's details.

We are using 'Customer Community Login' Custom profile and need to check the data by logging as Community User.

The issue is, I need to check if the queries are running smoothly and displaying the relevant data when logged in as Community User. How can I run the query as with logged in as Community User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create a visualforce page which displays response.
2. *Easier*- Use Salesforce `Session Id` of Community user for authentication, and test using any rest based tools like postman.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Rahul Sharma. Could you please help me n how to go ahead with the Session Id option.

Comment: Third option, create a custom button with type as onclick JavaScript. You can use session id from there.

Comment: Thanks... could you please suggest how to start with the 2nd option... Session id)